# How do I merge two count queries from one table?

Tags: c#, linq, join

The first query :

```
Id | UserId   |  projectId   |date   | Status
1  | 1        |  1           | 2020  | PENDDING
2  | 1        |  2           | 2020  | DONE
3  | 2        |  1           | 2020  | PENDDING
```

And what I tried two queries :
the first is about to get all userwork with X project for example id = 1

```
var FirstQery = context.table1.where (C => C.ProjectId == 1).count();
```

The second query is to fetch the number of user with project x have "done"status

```
var SecondQery = context.table1.where (C => C.ProjectId == 1 && C.Status == "DONE").count();
```

I want return object have only two values : countNumberUserWithXProject
and countNumberUserByXProjectHaveXStatus

Comment: The simpliest way : `var obj = new { countNumberUserWithXProject = FirstQery, countNumberUserByXProjectHaveXStatus = SecondQery };`

Comment: yes , i want do that in one query ? but i dont know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known approach with fake grouping.

```cs
var query = 
   from t in context.table1
   where t.ProjectId == 1
   group t by 1 into g
   select new 
   {
      Count = g.Count(),
      DoneCount = g.Sum(x => x.Status == "DONE" ? 1 : 0)
   }

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

How about returning an [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) (or if you like it more a typized object like a int[]).

```
return new {count1 = FirstQery , count2 = SecondQery };
```

(Return, or assign like var result = new {count1....} etc

You can also replace the FirstQuery and SecondQuery directly with the Linq query.

Comment: thanks for the answer ,yes this what i want , i want do that with the Linq query in one query? bu i dont know how

Comment: @resstel Doing what you ask is possible I think, but it gives no advantage in terms of performance and makes your code less readable. Not good. Leave it like this if I can give you this advice.